# overriding rails authenticity_token setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authenticity-token

Submitting a form requires a token which the receiving server has named `authenticity_token` and is expecting a string that is known only to posting and receiving servers:

```
<input id="authenticity_token" name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="ac513de198a9f0536df5003fb5ba3122d1ee53d5" />
```

that value renders if I call an instance or global variable.  However, even though the controller is set with the following filter:

```
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:reservation]
```

whether I try

```
<%= form_tag('https://test.webten.net/form') do %>
<%= hidden_field_tag :authenticity_token, @ppayment.authenticity_token, id: "authenticity_token" %>
```

or

```
<%= tag(:input, type: "hidden", name: request_forgery_protection_token.to_s, value: @ppayment.authenticity_token) %>
```

or

```
<input id="" name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="ac513de198a9f0536df5003fb5ba3122d1ee53d5" />
```

Rails ends up squashing each value with its own session setting value and rendering:

```
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" id="authenticity_token" value="ydi5En1ywUkN5VsYIBXu6JTbQmXtwxNhpKlyjbbLi3RdvCc+A59EdDZvroGsGFplAAE5ATLcSqw25LVQkyPtKw==">
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="ydi5En1ywUkN5VsYIBXu6JTbQmXtwxNhpKlyjbbLi3RdvCc+A59EdDZvroGsGFplAAE5ATLcSqw25LVQkyPtKw==">
<input id="authenticity_token" name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="ydi5En1ywUkN5VsYIBXu6JTbQmXtwxNhpKlyjbbLi3RdvCc+A59EdDZvroGsGFplAAE5ATLcSqw25LVQkyPtKw==">
```

How can rails default behaviour be overridden in this controller action?

Comment: Add some code showing how you're calling `form_for`, `form_tag` or `form_with` in your view. These all have an `:authenticity_token` argument that you may need to override.

Comment: I have updated the question to include `form_tag` in use

Comment: have you read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4085136/how-to-generate-authenticitytoken-on-rails there is a `<%= form_authenticity_token %>` and maybe by following that example you can get this to work? I'll try to help you more. Just let me know

Comment: I've seen this types of suggestions.  The problem here is setting the authenticity_token to a fixed value, NOT the current session's authenticity token.  i.e. the value needs to be set at `ac513de198a9f0536df5003fb5ba3122d1ee53d5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[*this answer is complementary to the preceeding one. It solves the issue, but in an inelegant manner*]

Various possible avenues of solution appear incomplete / off the mark

- `form_authenticity_token`is a view helper that returns the current
  session's authenticity token.  Too late to act upon that as the
  layout may already invoke it
- [most voted response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177863/how-do-i-ignore-the-authenticity-token-for-specific-actions-in-rails) has a per action method
  `protect_from_forgery` for ignoring it for internal purposes. Still
  is too late as session already has issued it
- [a skip before action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388243/disable-csrf-sitewide) is just like the previous solution, too
  late, session token is issued
- The [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#forms-to-external-resources) is incorrect in stating: `authenticity_token:
  'external_token'`

`Aaron Breckenridge`'s answer provide a clue: "you probably have some JS that overwrites the authenticity token ", supported by [this posting](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails/issues/202). Thus one could search the content of app directory and still not find a JS handler... when jquery-ujs, for example, is gem installed. Based on observed behaviour, it must be getting fired up every time it encounters `name='authenticity-token'` and sets the value based on the META tag (logical.  why have 2 different tokens on same page...) - doing its job properly!

Literally, that token must not be generated upstream.  So modifying the layout's header section:

```
<% unless  request.path == "/controller/action" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<% end %>
```

is a working solution. This solution gets pollution-prone for multiple paths. Another requires multiple layout handling... thus, file under 'kludgey'.  *(willing to entertain better one!)*

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the `:authenticity_token` argument in the `form_tag` call to prevent Rails from adding the session's authenticity token by default:

```
<%= form_tag('https://test.webten.net/form', authenticity_token: 'ac513de198a9f0536df5003fb5ba3122d1ee53d5') do %>
```

or:

```
<%= form_tag('https://test.webten.net/form', authenticity_token: false) do %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag 'authenticity_token', 'ac513de198a9f0536df5003fb5ba3122d1ee53d5' %>
```

If that doesn't work, you probably have some JS that overwrites the authenticity token you provided from the one in the META tag. Search for 'csrf-token' in your JS.

See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#forms-to-external-resources for more information.

Comment: I had tried both those variants in the form tag.  also, the string 'csrf-token' does not appear in any JS code, wither in views or assets directories. In every instance, the value is overwritten by the session crsf-token placed in the header `<meta name="csrf-token" content="[...]">`

Comment: would there be a way to hard code the desired string with escaping et al?  `<input id="authenticity_token" name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="ac513de198a9f0536df5003fb5ba3122d1ee53d5" />`  I have not succeded at that either...

Comment: You could hard code it with your own `META` tag in the `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`. Do you use the `jquery-rails` gem? It provides `jquery_ujs` in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`.